# How to display number of added items to Cart on "Cart" tab

Tags: android

I have a TabHost containing couple of tabs with one of the tab as "Cart". As soon as I add an item to cart, I want to display the count(number Of added items) on the "Cart" tab.

Can you please help me achieve that?

Comment: did u able to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

Make one static variable Counter when you click on addToCart Button then increment counter when you remove addTocart item then decrement counter.

Comment: Storing in a variable is not a problem. I am not sure how to display the counter on top of a Tab. Can you please help me out with that?

Comment: one can do that with `SharedPreferences` as using `Static` isn't advisable.

Comment: SharedPreferences will help me to store the count. But my problem is to display that on TabHost. I want to display a circled red image with the count displayed within it. Not sure how to achieve that on a TabHost